# Can not upload new main expansion file to Google Play console

Tags: android, upload, expansion

I have an app selling on Google Play store, and I have updated the main expansion file several times before. But when I uploaded new version apk today, I found that the main expansion file uploading was disabled(it showed the old expansion file name,and kept grey, can't be clicked), while the patch expansion file uploading is enabled. Does someone know anything about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing the reason, I found that the main expansion file uploading was enabled again after 2 days.